# VBA Dot notation

Tags: excel, vba

Hi so im new to programming specifically with VBA. Worked basics with Matlab previously so understand the for and if loops etc.
However I do not understand how the dot notation works. 
Meaning ActiveCell.Range etc

Where do we use it and in what context.

Thanks

Comment: Basicly the "." means, that you will either call a function or a property of the element before the "."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you're curious about how VBA defines what is happening in a line of code.

The VBA notation for working will be dependent on what you're doing, meaning how deep you will need to go.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula=""
```

This would be a pretty common display for a single line of code if you wanted a formula hard coded into A1.  You specify the workbook, the sheet, the cell/range to be worked in, then what you want to happen.

You can shorten some of this if you want to work do multiple things in the, arbitrarily, sheet (sheet1).  You can use a With statement which will have the following nomenclature:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     .Range("A1").Formula=""
     .Range("B1").Formula=""
End With
```

The use of the "." is what ties you do what is being operated on.  Think of it as part of a name.  Your name is Isra Shaikh (based on username).  If we want to punch you, and not your brother named Herb, we could want to specify:

```
SurName("Shaikh").PreName("Herb").Punch
```

If we wanted to punch both of you:

```
SurName("Shaikh").PreName("Isra").Punch
SurName("Shaikh").PreName("Herb").Punch
```

or more combined:

```
With SurName("Shaikh")
    .PreName("Isra").Punch
    .PreName("Herb").Punch
End With
```

Notice how the With statement doesn't end with a ".", but what happens inside the With is preceded with the "."; this is how VBA knows what all is being worked on.  Also note that you start from the widest, to the narrowest, component (workbook -> cell).

Hoping that is enough of a description!

Comment: Thanks! yeah trying to understand it as i use it so this seemed to be a common sight.
Makes so much sense now! Thankyou!